# axios base url from local json file

Tags: vue.js, axios

Tried to load baseURL for axios from local json file and export in variable "http" for use in applications. Tried to different way to implemetntation.Pls help

```
import axios from "axios";

const getURL = async () => {
    const resp = await axios.get('/config.json');
    return  axios.create({
        baseURL: resp.data.url,
    });
};
export const http = getURL();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with .env files https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html

Comment: the application is deployed on multiple servers. Each server must have its own baseURL. I want it to be a separate file that will be on each server

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vue-cli, then this would work for you:

Inside main.js file (this is entry point):

```js
import axios from 'axios'

/**
 * config.json implementation
 */
let axiosInstance = null

;(async () => {
  try {
    const config = await axios.get('/config.json')
    axiosInstance = axios.create({
      baseURL: config?.data?.url || 'some-fallback-url'
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn('Error!', err)
  } finally {
    Vue.prototype.$http = axiosInstance

    new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      render: h => h(App),
    }).$mount('#app')
  }
})()
```